# Can two quantum systems ever NOT interact?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

Given that two quantum systems will always be connected by fields, is it really possible for two quantum systems to remain completely unentangled? Even if the entanglement is destroyed by observation, won't the entanglement immediately creep back in?

Comment: You mean like a photon going through a transparent window? Or maybe a photon not affecting a neutron?

Comment: @mmesser314 Ahhh ok, well what about two systems that could conceivably interact? Like if we have two electrons is it possible for them to just remain completely unentangled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given that two quantum systems will always be connected by fields, is it really possible for two quantum systems to remain completely unentangled?

In the abstract: no, it is not possible.

In practice: entanglement is not really a black-and-white dichotomy, and the *degree* of entanglement matters a great deal. (Suitable measures are the purity of the state of the system, the entanglement entropy, and the entanglement spectrum, among others.) If you have a system which is in-principle in a pure state, but it has some unwanted van-der-Waals interactions with a hydrogen atom on the Moon which takes the purity from $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho^2)=1$ down to $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho^2)=1-10^{-10^{10}}$, does it really matter that the system is formally not factorizable? (particularly if you take into account that no practical measurement would ever be able to detect it.)

As a general rule, there are *extremely* few effects where the difference between a "truly" pure state, and a mixed state which is "$\epsilon$ away" from a pure state, actually makes any real difference; to the extent that such schemes exist, they are generally (and rightly) regarded with suspicion, as they represent an intolerance to noise and experimental uncertainty that is incompatible with practical reality.

---

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, this reasoning holds only if you want the system of interest to be in a pure state. It is possible to protect against entanglement (*with some pre-specified environment*) by placing your system in a mixed state. But, particularly if you start from a pure state, this can only be done by bringing in some ancilla system, entangling it with your system, and then discarding your ancilla.

(It is an open question, currently down to unanswerable questions of quantum interpretation, whether it is possible to ever have a "truly mixed" state, i.e. a system in a mixed state which is not in that condition because it is actually in a globally-pure entangled state with some other system out there which we're unable to identify.)

Comment: I quite disagree with the answer. Generally, the overall state will be mixed, and the separable (unentangled) mixed states form a set of non-zero measure. So it is very well possible to stay unentangled even if you are epsilon away from the state you thought you had.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I would argue that nothing is ever in a 'real' mixed state -- what looks like mixed states to us are simply globally-pure states that are entangled with some component of the environment which we are unable to find. But I appreciate that this is ultimately a philosophical stance with no objective resolution.

Comment: In any case, point taken: it is definitely possible to "protect" system S from becoming entangled with an environment E by putting it into a highly-mixed state, which can (only?) be accomplished by placing it into a highly-entangled state with an ancilla system A, and then discarding A. This protects S from entanglement with E, but it does not make S 'unentangled'.

Comment: *"But I appreciate that this is ultimately a philosophical stance with no objective resolution."*  Phew!  --- *"it is definitely possible to "protect" system S from becoming entangled with an environment E by putting it into a highly-mixed state"* : I would suspect that when you start from a pure product state, perturbing it in a random *mixed* direction (needs to be defined, obviously, but probably all reasonable definitions have non-singular relative measures) will leave it separable at least with a finite probability.

Comment: @Norbert I don't fully understand what you mean by "perturbing in a random mixed direction". But product states are *very* thin in measure in any joint Hilbert space, so I would find it an extremely remarkable result if 'most' interacting hamiltonians acting on 'most' product states kept the state on the separability submanifold with nonzero measure.

Comment: Indeed, product states are *zero* measure.  But so are Hamiltonian evolutions in the space of all noisy evolutions, so I would find it extremely remarkable if any interaction in nature would be *purely* Hamiltonian. And as soon as it is dissipative, it will change a pure product state $|\psi\rangle=|\psi_A\rangle\otimes|\psi_B\rangle$ to a mixed state $\rho$.  My claim is that for a generic $\rho$ s.th. $\||\psi\rangle\langle\psi|-\rho\|\le \epsilon$, with high probability (i.e. $p\to 1$ as $\epsilon\to 0$) $\rho$ will be unentangled (i.e. separable).  (Which is opposite to your answer.)

Comment: @Norbert How do you make a noisy evolution, if not as a hamiltonian evolution with an additional bath that's then traced out?